# How to find a node if parent node and child node has same name?

Tags: java, xml

I am working on a project in which I have to operate XML files using java. 
Earlier I was getting nodes by using node name, ie. `getElementsByTagName()`. Now a problem arises when I have an xml file with parent node and child node with same name.
How can I distinguish between them.

This a short sample of my xml file.

```
 <deviceparameters>
     <parameter>   // parent
        <name>ABC</name> 
        <parameter>Yes</parameter> // child with same name
        <value>20</value> 
     </parameter>
 </deviceparameters>
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: check if the node's `parentNode` has the same name? If it does, then you're in the child node.

Comment: @MarcB any special method for for checking the parent name.

Comment: I'm not a java coder, but any XML library that's not total garbage has methods to traverse a tree upwards and downwards, one of which will be a `parentNode` thing to get the current node's immediate ancestor.

Comment: A suggestion -> it would be better to use child-node(having same name as that of parent-node) as an attribute of parent-node , something like this -> '<parameter attributeName="[Yes|No]" >//parent<name>ABC</name><value>20</value></parameter>'

Comment: @RaviJain Thanks for your suggestion, but we have to use this format of xml was provided by our college.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Start with finding `deviceparameters` by name, and then find a named child `parameter` which is your first one, then then `parameter` child of that. The Javadoc will tell you the methods to use to find a named child (you may have to loop through the child elements).

Comment: Ok.. But code may become little complex. Any simple way, I mean so that I can directly jump to that node.

Comment: I don't think so. The whole thing of using the DOM is that you have to navigate. If you were using something like XPath you could just specify the path.

Comment: Does XPath really reduce the code. Which one will be better XPath or DOM?

Comment: Well XPath is more powerful as you can query things using paths, you can look at the APIs and decide for yourself, but in this instance you can just ask XPath for the node at `/deviceparameters/parameter/parameter`.

Comment: I'll try using XPath. Thanks for help.